# Is there a way to suppress a property when writing out a file with FileHelpers?

Tags: c#, filehelpers

Is there a way to suppress a property when writing out a file with FileHelpers?

Say I have an object:

```
[DelimitedRecord(",")]
public class MyClass
{
    public int Field1 { get; set; }
    public string Field2 { get; set; }
    public string Field3 { get; set; }
    public string Field4 { get; set; }
    public string Field5 { get; set; }
}
```

I want to write out a csv but I want to omit Field3 (regardless if it's populated or not).

Ex.

Output would be: Field1,Field2,Field4,Field5

Is there an attribute that I can use in FileHelpers to suppress writing out a file?

Answer (score 0):

From the documentation [here](http://www.filehelpers.net/mustread/) and [here](http://www.filehelpers.net/docs/html/P_FileHelpers_Dynamic_FieldBuilder_FieldValueDiscarded.htm) you would use the FieldValueDiscarded attribute.  Here is the full blurb:

> Use the FieldValueDiscarded attribute for fields that you don't use.
>
> If your record class has some fields that are not used, the library will discard the value of fields marked by this attribute

Comment: That only appears to work on fields not properties.  I'll have to play around with that some because I get an error when I convert the property to the field.  The class that I'm using has 70+ properties to them.

Answer (score 0):

As a workaround, you can use an `AfterWrite` event to remove the last delimiter. Something like this:

```
[DelimitedRecord(",")]
class Product : INotifyWrite
{
    [FieldQuoted(QuoteMode.AlwaysQuoted)]
    public string Name;
    [FieldQuoted(QuoteMode.AlwaysQuoted)]
    public string Description;
    [FieldOptional]
    public string Size;

    public void BeforeWrite(BeforeWriteEventArgs e)
    {
        // prevent output of [FieldOptional] Size field
        Size = null;
    }

    public void AfterWrite(AfterWriteEventArgs e)
    {
        // remove last "delimiter"
        e.RecordLine = e.RecordLine.Remove(e.RecordLine.Length - 1, 1);
    }
}

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var engine = new FileHelperEngine<Product>();
        var products = new Product[] { new Product() { Name = "Product", Description = "Details", Size = "Large"} };
        var productRecords = engine.WriteString(products);
        try
        {
            // Make sure Size field is not part of the output
            Assert.AreEqual(@"""Product"",""Details""" + Environment.NewLine, productRecords);
            Console.WriteLine("All tests pass");
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("An error occurred");
            Console.WriteLine(ex);
        }

        Console.ReadKey();
    }
}
```